# Guidelines or resources for making a remote video processing application

Tags: image-processing, architecture, video-streaming

I am working on an application that takes a stream of images from the user's camera, sends it to a server, does some processing and then sends the processed stream back to the user, while the server keeps track of the "session" with the user, hopefully in real time. Currently I just grabbed the code from [here](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/) and modified it to receive and send images, which kind of works, but I know there has to be better approaches than that, at least regarding image compression and dropping frames when the connection degrades and anything else I may be missing. I have read about [WebRTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC) but it's for browsers, and I'm building a desktop application. Since I'm sure this is not the first time someone tries to build something like this, are there any guidelines, common libraries (preferably in Python) or general resources for this kind of architecture?

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC is an API that is intended for browsers. The capability it provides is a media stack that transmits audio and video in realtime which seems to be what you are looking for.

https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc
provides a python implementation of WebRTC and its underlying protocols.